# How Single Link Flexible Manipulator Controller controls the vibration of the link tip?

Tags: control-engineering

I'm control engineering student.

As seen on the video link below, how the controller controls the tip vibration and the link movement at the same time? Please explain using the block diagram of the system, since i am quite confused.

I already know about simple feedback controllers. For instance if i have a simple dc motor position control. How it works is if the *now position* of the motor is less than the setpoint, the controller add a little bit power to the motor so the motor turns. Otherwise, if the *now position* is more than the setpoint, controller trying to reduce power or inverse the polarity of the power given to match by the setpoint.

But for the flexible manipulator i have no idea about how the control system works. Since the controller must regulate the motor speed and direction of rotation to somehow reduce the tip vibration.

[Single Link Flexible Manipulator Controller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VF673MGugjY)

Comment: What knowledge do you have already of control theory? For example this system SIMO. Did your education already cover this or the even more general case of MIMO?

Comment: What i know about SIMO/MIMO system is only about their definition. Since it is not yet covered in my Ed.

Comment: Then I think it would be better to wait until this is covered in more depth in your education, because otherwise this would need to be a very elaborate answer.

Comment: Do you know the answer? Even if it is only simplest explanation. That would be much help. Thank you in advance

Comment: I so not know the exact algorithm used for the control law, but I could speculate.